# State machine implementation on legacy system

Tags: state-machine

I am very new to this subject, please let me know if you need more context.

I have an old legacy system with lots of complicated business logic/states that we are trying to extract and re-implement in a state machine.

Let's suppose I need to do something similar:

1. Save a User to the state "Approved"
2. Reject if the user data does not satisfy some conditions
3. Accept the change otherwise, save the User and send a notification

My understanding is that between 1. and 2. I need to call the state machine providing the new data (filled from a web form).

The state machine needs to get the current state from the database to understand what is the original state and verify if the conditions for switching the state to "Approved" are met.

Is my understanding right?

Thank you